# How can I restrict a user to view different reports

Tags: reporting

How can I restrict a user to view different reports in salesforce? What is the difference between folder accessibilty and reports?

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why a user cannot run a report. They are: the profile permission Run Reports, access to the underlying data types, and folder access.

The first permission affects the user's ability to run any report, the second the ability to run all reports of a particular data type, and the third affects all reports in a folder.

As you can see, there isn't a way to restrict access to a report directly. To make sure a user can't run a report, place it in a folder they don't have access to.